# Website Region Blocked?

Tags: dns, hosting, http-status-code-403

I'm having trouble with a website we have created. It currently lives on **Rackspace Cloud Sites** and uses **Cloudflare**. All well and good, until you are on the western part of the United States.

It seems that for some reason people out west seem to either get erratic behavior from the site like random things not working correctly, or they are flat out denied access to the site completely with just the words Forbidden on in the browser window.

I've talked with Rackspace tech support and Cloudflare and they both are telling me that they aren't the cause of the block.

This leads me down the path that there could possible be a bad DNS server sitting somewhere that a few ISPs all share that might be having trouble.

Does anyone have any thoughts about what I should be looking for to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

1] You visit http://intodns.com/, enter your domain and fetch report.Check your NS record and make sure it doesn't differ. Example: Domain name -xyz.com then NS record should like ns1.xyz.com-->IP and ns2.xyz.com-->IP

2]Disable DNS recursion and remove all root hints from DNS Manager.

3]Flush your DNS by running command ipconfig /flushdns

4]Donot make frequent changes in NS records because global propagation will take almost 24-48 hours time.

5]Forbidden page error, you need to check permission of folders/files and dependent all child folders/files

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Everything you recommended was tried, but there is still no luck.